# Updating column values based on the other table values in hive tables

Tags: mysql, hive

I have two tables like below in hive

`stg`. This table is bascially snapshot table which will be overwritten everyday

This table data will be inserted to `history` table every day in new `partition`

`Day 1`

`stg` table

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| pk  | from_d     | to_d       |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 222 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 333 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

`history` This table is partitioned by column `load_date`

```
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| pk  | from_d     | to_d       |load_date   |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 222 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 333 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
```

Problem statement:

1) If I receieve any `PK` that is already present in `history` table then I will need to update the `to_d` column for that PK in history.

2) The `to_d` column should have value of `from_d - 1 day` value in the `STG` table.

3) Also need to consider if the `PK` is again coming in another day then the update should happen to only the latest record in history not all the records for the same PK.

Please check PK `111` in the below data examples.

`Day 2`

`stg`

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| pk  | from_d     | to_d       |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 333 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 444 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

`history` table to be updated like below

```
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| pk  | from_d     | to_d       | load_date  |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 222 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 333 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 333 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 444 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
```

To achieve the above first I have updated the history table using

```
insert overwrite table histroy partition(load_date) 
    select pk, from_d, 
    case when pk = '111' then '2019-02-01' when pk = '333' then '2019-02-01' else to_d end as to_d, 
    load_date 
from history;
```

once this is done then I have inserted the day 2 stg table to history table

`Day 3`

`stg`

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| pk  | from_d     | to_d       |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 222 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 555 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

`history` to be uodated like below

```
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| pk  | from_d     | to_d       | load_date  |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 222 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-02 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 333 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-01-01 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-03-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 333 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 444 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 222 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 555 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-03 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
```

To achieve  the above I have done

```
insert overwrite table histroy partition(load_date) 
    select pk, from_d, 
    case when pk = '111' then '2019-03-02' else to_d end as to_d, 
    load_date 
from history 
where load_date = '2019-02-02';

insert overwrite table history partition(load_date) 
    select pk, from_d, 
    case when pk = '222' then '2019-03-02' else to_d end as to_d, 
    load_date 
from history 
where load_date = '2019-01-01';
```

Then insert the `STG` table data

I am achieving what I want but this is a tedious process and there must be better approaches than this one.

Note: I don't want to use the `Update` statements for this problem. Insert overwrite is what I am looking for

Comment: Histroy <> history

Comment: @Strawberry it is a typo both are same

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below

First create a table and assign row_number for each row partitioned by `PK` like below

```
create table stg_row_num as select *, 
               row_number() over ( partition by pk order by load_date desc) as row_num from stg;
```

The above query should give you table like below

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| pk|    from_d|      to_d| load_date| row_num|
+---+----------+----------+----------+--------+
|111|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|       1|
|111|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|       2|
|111|2019-01-01|2019-01-01|2019-01-01|       3|
|222|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|       1|
|222|2019-01-01|2019-01-01|2019-01-01|       2|
|333|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|       1|
|333|2019-01-01|2019-01-01|2019-01-01|       2|
|444|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|       1|
|555|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|       1|
+---+----------+----------+----------+--------+
```

Once you have the above table then using `LAG` function like below

```
select pk, from_d,           
            case when row_num = 1 then to_d else date_sub(lag(to_d) over (), 1) end as to_d, 
            row_num from table;
```

This will give you the desired result

```
+---+----------+----------+-------------------+
| pk|    from_d|      to_d|row_number_window_0|
+---+----------+----------+-------------------+
|111|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|                  1|
|111|2019-02-02|2019-03-02|                  2|
|111|2019-01-01|2019-02-01|                  3|
|222|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|                  1|
|222|2019-01-01|2019-03-02|                  2|
|333|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|                  1|
|333|2019-01-01|2019-02-01|                  2|
|444|2019-02-02|2019-02-02|                  1|
|555|2019-03-03|2019-03-03|                  1|
+---+----------+----------+-------------------+
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in 2 steps which might be better in terms of performance.

1.Create a temporary table with `load_date` ranking for each `pk`. This table can be overwritten every time the job/script runs.

```
create table if not exists rank_load_date_pk as 
select pk,from_d,to_d,row_number() over(partition by pk order by load_date desc) as rnum
from history
;
```

2.There are 3 scenarios which should be handled next.

- `pk`s existing in both `stg` and `history`. In this case, the latest row prior should be selected with the appropriate calculation for `to_d`
- Remaining `pk`s from `history`. In this case, select all the non-latest rows for each `pk`
- All rows from `stg`

SQL

```
insert overwrite table history partition(load_date) 
--common pk's with the latest load_date rows
select r.pk,r.from_d,coalesce(date_sub(s.to_d,1),r.to_d) as to_d,coalesce(s.to_d,r.load_date) as load_date
from rank_load_date_pk r
left join stg s on s.pk = r.pk 
where r.rnum = 1
union all
--remaining rows
select pk,from_d,to_d,load_date
from rank_load_date_pk 
where rnum > 1
union all
--stg all rows
select pk,from_d,to_d,to_d as load_date
from stg 
;
```